# Mudar texto <span> com jQuery+variável

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-core

Estou tentando alterar o texto exibido por um `span` dentro de um modal:

```
<div class="modal-body">Deseja realmente excluir?<span id="nomecliente"></span></div>
```

Estou usando `onclick` para passar o valor para usar no jQuery.

```
<td style="text-align:center" onclick="Excluir(@item.nome)"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-circle btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#excluirmodal"></button></td>
```

E a minha função JS/jQuery é essa:

```
function Excluir(nome) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#nomecliente').html(nome);
    })
}
```

Já tentei mudar o `.html` para `.text` e não funcionou, e o mais estranho é se tento passar um número ele funciona, exibe no modal normalmente, mas string não estou conseguindo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa delimitar a string na função do `onclick` com aspas simples, nesse caso:

```
onclick="Excluir('@item.nome')"
```

Senão irá dar erro, porque ficaria uma string sem delimitador, tipo:

```
onclick="Excluir(fulano de tal)"
```

Sem o delimitador, a string será interpretada como uma variável ou um código a ser interpretado que não existe.

No caso do número funciona porque número não precisa necessariamente de um delimitador:

Poderia ser `onclick="Excluir(123)"` ou `onclick="Excluir('123')"`.

> Outra coisa:

O `$(document).ready...` usado dentro da função não tem nenhum efeito ou sentido. O correto seria apenas:

```
function Excluir(nome) {
    $('#nomecliente').html(nome);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, deu certo.